# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am using VS 2017 for an Visual C# application (.Net 4.6.2, 32 bit) that calls a form from the main form. In that second form the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is not firing for one of the `ComboBoxes`. Following is the code. If I have to register the event I don't know how. I originally had copied and pasted the `ComboBoxes` onto the form. Then I deleted that control and re-added the `ComboBoxes` from the ToolBox. Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace Lottery_C_Sharp
{
    public partial class Dialog_Matches_Input_Lotomania : Form
    {
        MatchesMethods_LM m;
        public string[] lotomania_list = new string[10];
        public string[] pick10_list = new string[5];
        Utilities u;

        public Dialog_Matches_Input_Lotomania(MatchesMethods_LM mm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m = mm;
            u = new Utilities();
            set_combos(); 

            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged");

            if (m.NumCurrLimit == 99)
            {
                set_lotomania_time_text();
                set_lotomania_totals_text();
            }
            else
            {
                set_pick10_time_text();
                set_pick10_totals_text();
            }
        }

        public void set_combos()
        {
            set_lists();

            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();

            if (m.NumCurrLimit == 99)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Brazilian LotoMania";

                AddToCombo(comboBox1, lotomania_list);
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

                AddToCombo(comboBox2, lotomania_list);
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;

                AddToCombo(comboBox3, lotomania_list);
                comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;

                set_lotomania_time_text();
                set_lotomania_totals_text();

            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "USA New York Pick 10";

                AddToCombo(comboBox1, pick10_list);
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

                AddToCombo(comboBox2, pick10_list);
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;

                AddToCombo(comboBox3, pick10_list);
                comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;

                set_pick10_time_text();
                set_pick10_totals_text();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you register the event listener `SelectedIndexChanged`  for that combobox ? Something like `comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged);`

Comment: No I didn't. Where would I place that code?

Comment: If this is WinForms then go to the designer, select the control, select the lightning icon in Properties view and connect the event. And also from the beginning name the controls properly. In a moment you won’t know what `comboBox2` is even yourself.

Comment: ^---- This is the simpliest way. VS will generate and register automatically the event to a method

Comment: @ Cid I placed the code in the constructor. It is working now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register the event for Your desired combobox in Designer properties, like this:
[image: How to register event in WinForms Designer]

It generates event registration in `Form1.Designer.cs` (form name depends on how You've named it) auto-generated file:

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Then Your function, where You can perform some actions when event occures shows in `Form1.cs`

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to register the event.

**Option 1:**

Register in code:

```cs
public Dialog_Matches_Input_Lotomania(MatchesMethods_LM mm)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ...

    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Double click on `comboBox1` in the designer, this will automatically add and register an event.

**Option 3:**

Select the `comboBox1` in the designer, right click and select "Properties", in the properties window select the event icon on top (the lightning symbol), find "SelectedIndexChanged" and enter the name of the event or double click to automatically add and register an event.